# pthread.h - Is voluntary CPU yield the only trigger to scheduling another user-level thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

Is voluntary yield of CPU the only way threads in the linux pthread library can enable scheduling another thread under the same process ? (Because pthread is a user-level thread implementation ?)

It seems the pthread_yield() and the mutexes (provided by the pthread library) are the only way to invoke the scheduler to start another thread's execution. Is that true ?

Comment: The behavior you are describing is `co-operative multitasking`.  Such behavior can be seen in very ancient operating systems with no built-in multithreading support, where the threading libraries are implemented at the user-level only (such implementations are sometimes called "green threads").  Almost all modern OS's, however, use `preemptive multitasking`, which means that the kernel is thread-aware and can move threads on and off of the CPU at any time it wants to.  Under modern OS's, pthread_yield() is superfluous, as threads will be 'auto-yielded' whenever the OS thinks it appropriate.

Comment: In Linux, each user-level thread is implemented via a corresponding kernel-level thread, so pthreads.h provides full preemptive multitasking.

Comment: Re, "...Because pthread is a user-level thread implementation..." the pthreads library was that, maybe twenty years ago. These days, it's a standard API, that practically always is implemented using system calls that create real OS threads.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy and besmirched for your answers (given in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, any call that also blocks the current thread will schedule another tread. This includes library calls such as sleep(), read(), select(), pthread_mutex_lock()  and many others.

Note that pthread is not a pure user level thread implementation on linux, it maps 1 user mode thread to 1 kernel task.

Comment: By read() you mean the system call that traps to the kernel, right ? However, you mentioned that the thread is mapped to a kernel task. Is there a webpage that explains this implementation ?

Comment: Yes, that's what the read() call does. See the docs, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html and the design paper, https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/nptl-design.pdf